# Add 2 custom button to QUILL editor

Tags: javascript, quill

i'm trying to customize my quill editor to show 2 additional buttons

1. the first button when pressed showld insert a DIVIDER into the html like this:

   div class="text-center h5 mb-4">. . .</div
2. the second button , after selecting a letter should meake it capital adding this code surrounding the selected letter:

   span class="dropcap">A</span

This is the configuration code for quill editor in my html template form:

```
    // START: 16 Quill Editor
quill: function () {
  window.editor = []
  e.selectAll('[data-quilleditor]').forEach(function(item) {
        var editor = new Quill('[data-quilleditor="'+item.dataset.quilleditor+'"]', {
            modules: { toolbar: '[data-quilltoolbar="'+item.dataset.quilleditor+'"]' },
            theme: 'snow',
            placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
        });
        editor.enable(item.dataset.quilldisabled != 'true')
        window.editor.push({
            lang: item.dataset.lang,
            quilleditor: item.dataset.quilleditor,
            editor: editor,
        })
        
  })
},
// END: Quill Editor
```

I tried to follow some tutorial i foun around but i was unable to do it:

[How to add quill custom button working example](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2611)